# Info about input method and keyboard layout

Tags: debian, xfce, devuan, ibus

I'm using Devuan GNU/Linux [based on Debian 11 Bullseye].
I have Xfce as my DE and use ibus-m17n as my input tool.

In Ubuntu, in the I-Bus settings dialog, I used to find the keyboard layout for the chosen language. The last version of Ubuntu that I used was 16.04 LTS.

Ever since I shifted to Debian and eventually Devuan, I don't find that keyboard layout option. What I get is some sort of an overlay when I hover the mouse over the particular input method. I have provided the link for two such overlays below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XAAr.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMzoK.png

**Question**

1. How can I get the full information shown in the overlays?
2. How can I see the keyboard layout for the chosen input method?

Kindly help.

Regards,
Vrajaraja Govinda Das.

Comment: Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the very easy-to-read .MIM files in `/usr/share/m17n/`.

These files have all the necessary information.

Thanks to Mohan, senior member of Indian Linux User Group - Chennai [ILUGC] for sharing this.